# Как сделать так, чтобы файл выбирался и отправлялся автоматически?

Tags: html, upload

Примерно такой код:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Отправка файла на сервер</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <p><input type="file" name="f">
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо выбора файла и отправления он сам выбирался и отправлялся автоматически?

Comment: А где у вас тут файл выбирается?

Comment: Исправил, не тот код был.

Comment: Выбирать стандартными средствами никак, безопасность. А отправлять автоматически: `XmlHttpRequest`,`ajax`.